# Sklearn LinearRegression() don't require Iterations and Learning rate as parameter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

As far as I know the cost is minimized using the Gradient Descent algorithm by updating the weights(repeat until convergence), In case of linear regression we have

```
m : slope

c : intercept (constant value)
```

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x= np.asarray([(i+np.random.randint(1,7)) for i in range(1,31)]).reshape(-1,1)

y= np.dot([3],x.T) + 5

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(x,y)
```

I have used the sklearn library but here we're not taking iterations and the learning rate as input at the time of initialization or doing `reg.fit()`.

Why does not sklearn's linear regression asks for iterations and learning rate? Is it set with some default value or it uses some other method?

Comment: `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` is simple least squares regression, as the documentation states.  It does not iterate.

Comment: linear regression has a closed forn. And no, the cost is not minimized by gradient descent, but rather the coeficients are solved using using various options. qr decomposition with back/forward solve being the most commonly used. am convinced numpy/sklearn uses LAPACK fortran functions for this task

Comment: sklearn's `Lineargression.fit(X,Y)` is just the same as `np.linalg.inv(X.T@X)@X.T@Y`. I am slightly oversimplying here. But just a bit slightly. It is true only for LinearRegression with `fit_intercept=False` (but to have the same result as with default True, you just need to add a column of `1` to your data, and the coefficient matching the 1 is the intercept). And also, implementation is probably more efficient that direct inversion (Moore-Penrose's inverse: (XᵀX)⁻¹Xᵀ), with some LU decomposition probably (even tho numpy's inverse is probably optimized too).

Comment: Point is, it is a very simple, one-step, deterministic, linear algebra operation. Not an iterative, learning/optimization process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearRegression()` doesn't use gradient descent, which is why it does not have a `learning_rate` parameter. Instead, it uses a mathematical formula for directly computing the optimal coefficients. In other words, it has a closed-form solution, so an iterative solver like gradient descent is not required.

Gradient descent is a more general approach that can handle more complex problems. You could still use it for linear regression though - [check out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html) `SGDRegressor()`.

Both `LinearRegression` and `SGDRegressor(penalty=None)` will find the same optimal weights for the linear model you outlined. The difference is in *how* they get there. The former computes an exact solution directly, whereas the latter steps along the steepest gradient regions to eventually converge at the global optimum.

There are circumstances where you might need to use one solver rather than the other, one example being that if your dataset is too big to fit into memory then you can't use `LinearRegression` since it needs to see all the data at the same time. `SGDRegressor` would work because gradient descent can break the data down into minibatches and iterate towards the solution one minibatch at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a demonstration to Muhammed's answer (you should accept it, btw), here is an example

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12) # Just to have a reproducible example
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
X=np.random.normal(0,1,(20,10)) # Or any array of X you want. Just a mre
Y=np.random.normal(0,1,(20,))

# Learning with LinearRegerssion, without intercept (so learning M, Y=LX, L begin an array of coefficients)
reg=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)
reg.fit(X,Y)
print(reg.coef_) # The coefficients. 
# With my random example and seed, shows
#[-0.06999151 -0.0586993   0.77203288  0.11928812  0.05656448 -0.37281412
# -0.35447307  0.06957882  0.26701851  0.06950227]
# Meaning that model is to predict that Y=-0.06999151*X₀ -0.0586993*X₁ + ...

# For example prediction for a given X
Xtest=np.random.randint(-5,5, (1,10)) # A single sample of 10 features
reg.predict(Xtest)
# returns 4.49749641
# Which is simply
sum(Xtest[0,i]*reg.coef_[i] for i in range(10))
# Or, using linear algebra operation
reg.coef_@Xtest[0]

# Now, Moore-Penrose's version
Coef = np.linalg.inv(X.T@X)@X.T@Y
print(Coef)
#[-0.06999151 -0.0586993   0.77203288  0.11928812  0.05656448 -0.37281412
# -0.35447307  0.06957882  0.26701851  0.06950227]
# See, same coefficients! Not "approximately the same". But the same... 
# including the non significative decimal places, where you would expect some
# numerical error. Showing that it is really the same computation done, not an equivalent one

# prediction is likewise
Coef@Xtest[0]
```

So, no mystery here. LinearRegression is just a Moore-Penrose's pseudo inverse. Aka a least-square value. Aka an orthogonal projection (same thing: point P of subspace Vec(X₁,X₂,...) for which distance ‖X-P‖ is minimum is also the orthogonal projection of X onto subspace Vec(X₁,X₂,...)

And even if you have no recollection of notion such as subspace, Vec, Moore-Penrose, ... (I say "recollection" because, probably, if your are doing this kind of stuff, you probably had some math lesson at university/college degree at some point; and that is something that is taught in any scientific curiculum in the world... but that most people quickly forget later), at least, you can see that it is not an iterative process. Just a formula (XᵀX)⁻¹XᵀY

I've simplified my example here, because I've removed the intercept. But the intercept is just the coefficent to an extra "1" vector.

```py
X1=np.ones((20,11))
X1[:,:10]=X
CoefI = np.linalg.inv(X1.T@X1)@X1.T@Y
# Returns
# array([-0.1068548 , -0.09027332,  0.73712907,  0.1136123 ,  0.0904737 ,
#       -0.36593051, -0.38649945,  0.02849317,  0.18063291,  0.05866195,
#       -0.17597287])
regI=LinearRegression()
regI.fit(X,Y)
regI.coef_
#array([-0.1068548 , -0.09027332,  0.73712907,  0.1136123 ,  0.0904737 ,
#       -0.36593051, -0.38649945,  0.02849317,  0.18063291,  0.05866195])
# aka the 10 first coefficients (the one apply to the 10 "real" columns of X)
regI.intercept_
#-0.17597287204667314
# aka the 11th coefficient of Moore-Penrose's inverse. That is the one
# apply to the "all 1" vector. 

# Comparison of prediction is almost as easy
regI.predict(Xtest)
CoefI[:10]@Xtest[0]+CoefI[10]
# both return the same 4.633604110000001
```

So, even with intercept, it is still just a linear algebra formula, not an interative process.

May be sklearn is more efficient. But that is not obvious with normal size dataset (with small examples, like my 20×10, direct Moore-Penrose is 10 times faster. But that is probably just because of the overhead of class initialization. But even with big datasets like 2000×1000 — still not huge tho — Moore Penrose is still 3 times faster. Maybe it is because sklearn ensure some better conditioning. Or maybe it works better with way bigger dataset with sparse values. I don't know). From a math perspective it does nothing more than a Moore-Penrose inverse. From an implementation perspective, it is not easy to exhibit example of what it does more (it is not faster, and I could not generate examples where it is more stable)

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, generally an iterative solution isn't used; **however**, it does happen when the input is a sparse matrix. In that case, sklearn currently just relies on the default parameters from the scipy sparse solver `lsqr`.  [Issue24601](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/24601) suggests adding some of those parameters to the sklearn API.

Other optimization suggestions, for dense as well as sparse inputs:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/22855
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/23199
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/14268